How do I get the positions on the frontpage of my website right?
Website idea
Up until now
The first picture is the way I want my website to look like. So the Title in the middle of the header elements. The title has a black border around it.
Underneath the header and the title, I want a picture, also with a black border around it.
Then in the middle I want the search bar, again with a black border around it.
And then underneath that, I want a section that shows a little bit what you can expect from the website.
But the second picture is what I've got until now. I'm really stuck, and can't even get the title and header right.
If someone could help me out, a little bit is also okay, that would be great!


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Cambria;
  height: 757.58px;
  width: 1100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #91CDB7;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

.main-content {
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}

.main-content span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 388px;
  height: 93px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #91CDB7;
  font-size: 58px;
  line-height: 73px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
}

.header-container:nth-child(1) {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px
  /* Eerste header-container links uitlijnen */
}

.header-container:nth-child(2) {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  /* Tweede header-container rechts uitlijnen */
}
<div class="header-container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Recepten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Muziek</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="header-container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Wedstrijden</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <span>Music Bakery</span>
</div>



This is the code I've got until now. I was hoping this would do the trick for the title and the header, but sadly it doesn't.

What are you stuck with? What issue occurs when you attempt to add more elements to the webpage?

You might find grid easier to use as this is a 2D layout.

I changed quite a bit of what you had, but this should be a bit of a better setup for you to work with. I'd suggest adjusting the fixed heights and widths to be more responsive with breakpoints eventually, but this is the desired layout you're going for.


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Cambria;
  height: 757.58px;
  width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

nav, nav ul  {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #91CDB7;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

.main-content-title {
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}

.main-content-title span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 88px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #91CDB7;
  font-size: 58px;
  line-height: 73px;
  position: relative;
}
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Recepten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Muziek</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Wedstrijden</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="main-content-title">
      <span>Music Bakery</span>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content-img">
      <img>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>




To add to this... I would also recommend NOT using absolute positioning for layouts, its generally frowned upon for this. Absolute postioning is not good for responsive styling and can take elements out of the flow of the document which could lead to other issues

Hi, first of all, thank you for this code, this really helped me out!
I had another question, do you maybe now how I can create layers in my code, so that, as you can see in the first picture, the title "Music Bakery" is covering a part of the picture.

Yep! This would be done with z-index. Search up this term and get a better idea of how to use z-index and you'll be on your way
